# Why are god objects so common in game programming?

Tags: c++, unreal, oop

This is a bit of a philosophical question. Excuse me if it's out of place here.

Most modern games developed in C++ use (or at least purport to use) an object-oriented approach. A common axiom of object-oriented design is that a class should have a single, self-evident responsibility. I think that's good advice: You should be able to look at a class definition, take in the list of member functions, and know what a class is designed to do. If your public interface has 50+ functions, you're probably doing something wrong.

Here is the list of *public* member functions declared in the player character class for Unreal's sample shooter game.

```
class AShooterCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    virtual void PostInitializeComponents() override;
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaSeconds) override;
    virtual void Destroyed() override;
    virtual void PawnClientRestart() override;
    virtual void PossessedBy(class AController* C) override;
    virtual void OnRep_PlayerState() override;
    void OnCameraUpdate(const FVector& CameraLocation, const FRotator& CameraRotation);
    FRotator GetAimOffsets() const;
    bool IsEnemyFor(AController* TestPC) const;
    void AddWeapon(class AShooterWeapon* Weapon);
    void RemoveWeapon(class AShooterWeapon* Weapon);
    class AShooterWeapon* FindWeapon(TSubclassOf<class AShooterWeapon> WeaponClass);
    void EquipWeapon(class AShooterWeapon* Weapon);
    void StartWeaponFire();
    void StopWeaponFire();
    bool CanFire() const;
    bool CanReload() const;
    void SetTargeting(bool bNewTargeting);
    void SetRunning(bool bNewRunning, bool bToggle);
    virtual float PlayAnimMontage(class UAnimMontage* AnimMontage, float InPlayRate = 1.f, FName StartSectionName = NAME_None) override;
    virtual void StopAnimMontage(class UAnimMontage* AnimMontage) override;
    void StopAllAnimMontages();
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* InputComponent) override;
    void MoveForward(float Val);
    void MoveRight(float Val);
    void MoveUp(float Val);
    void TurnAtRate(float Val);
    void LookUpAtRate(float Val);
    void OnStartFire();
    void OnStopFire();
    void OnStartTargeting();
    void OnStopTargeting();
    void OnNextWeapon();
    void OnPrevWeapon();
    void OnReload();
    void OnStartJump();
    void OnStopJump();
    void OnStartRunning();
    void OnStartRunningToggle();
    void OnStopRunning();
    USkeletalMeshComponent* GetPawnMesh() const;
    class AShooterWeapon* GetWeapon() const;
    FName GetWeaponAttachPoint() const;
    int32 GetInventoryCount() const;
    class AShooterWeapon* GetInventoryWeapon(int32 index) const;
    float GetTargetingSpeedModifier() const;
    bool IsTargeting() const;
    bool IsFiring() const;
    float GetRunningSpeedModifier() const;
    bool IsRunning() const;
    virtual bool IsFirstPerson() const;
    int32 GetMaxHealth() const;
    bool IsAlive() const;
    float GetLowHealthPercentage() const;
    USkeletalMeshComponent* GetSpecifcPawnMesh(bool WantFirstPerson) const;
    void UpdateTeamColorsAllMIDs();
    virtual float TakeDamage(float Damage, struct FDamageEvent const& DamageEvent, class AController* EventInstigator, class AActor* DamageCauser) override;
    virtual void Suicide();
    virtual void KilledBy(class APawn* EventInstigator);
    virtual bool CanDie(float KillingDamage, FDamageEvent const& DamageEvent, AController* Killer, AActor* DamageCauser) const;
    virtual bool Die(float KillingDamage, struct FDamageEvent const& DamageEvent, class AController* Killer, class AActor* DamageCauser);
    virtual void FellOutOfWorld(const class UDamageType& dmgType) override;
    virtual void PreReplication( IRepChangedPropertyTracker & ChangedPropertyTracker ) override;
};
```

Why is this acceptable? Isn't there a better way?

Comment: It's definitely not acceptable to everybody. But speculation on why it still persists in some code bases is pretty discussion oriented. Perhaps try the [chat]?

Comment: Whenever developing software, there is always the ideal solution that is written out on paper, discussed with peers, and tested against the recommendations of the C++ prophets (Scott Meyers/Herb Sutter, and more). Then your solution is taken out of it's isolated environment, and thrown into the roughest arena out there, the production code arena. This is where all your planning, and expectations start to fall apart, as the reality of interfacing with code that you don't control, is never ideal. Production code is a balance between idealistic design, and realistic practicality.

Comment: Why is this acceptable?  Because it works well enough in practice.  OOP design principles are ideals.  Even if you accept OOP principles as appropriate ideals for a game engine—which not everyone does—they have to be balanced against real-world productivity, which can be hurt by spending too much time chasing after a design ideal.

Comment: There is a better way: entity/component systems. Google it please. It is quite awesome, actually, and solves many of the problems of this monolithic-object model.

Comment: Maybe this question is too soft for GDSE, but it could work on Programmers.